# I can't get session from jsp

Tags: jsp, session, servlets

I'm going to try to explain my problem.
I have a login.jsp, where you fill the user name and password and send it to a servlet, this servlet check with database and if it's right call to userLogged.jsp and if it isn't right send to invalidLogin.jsp.
This works fine, even when I get userlogged.jsp, I can retrieve the session data that I created in the servlet.
Userlogged.jsp creates a html page with three parts, one button to continue, one form to change password and one banner. Then when I click on button to continue, I call the servlet, but here I can't get the session, always is null.
How can I pass when I click the button the session information to servlet?
I paste the code, if you need more information please let me know. Thank you.

SERVLET

```
    private void getLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, DataAccessUtils dao) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String userName = request.getParameter("username");
    String userPassword = request.getParameter("password");

            // DATABASE ACCESS
    Login login = new Login();
    String[] currentUser = login.validateLogin(userName, userPassword, dao);

    if (!currentUser[0].equals("-1"))
    {                 
        String nextJSP = "/actions/userLogged.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);     
        session.setAttribute("username", currentUser[0]);                   
        session.setAttribute("agencyname", currentUser[1]);
        session.setAttribute("branchname", currentUser[2]);
        session.setAttribute("currenttravelfile", "N/A");

        dispatcher.forward(request,response);
    }                   
    else
    {
        response.sendRedirect("actions/invalidLogin.jsp"); //error page 
    }
}

private void getGoToMenu(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, DataAccessUtils dao) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    // HERE ALWAYS IS NULL  
    String username = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("username");

    String nextJSP = "/actions/menu.jsp";       
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
    dispatcher.forward(request,response);
}
```

USERLOGGED.jsp (only the part where I call servlet)

```
            <form action="./getjsprequestservlet" method="post" id="userlogged-form">       
            <fieldset>
                <div style="margin-bottom:1em; margin-left: 11em;">     
                    <input type=hidden name=action id=opr value="gotomenu"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Go To Menu" class="button round blue image-right ic-right-arrow"></input>
                </div>


                <div class="information-box round">
                    <input type=hidden name=action id=opr value="change-password"/>
                    <p>
                        <label class="title">Change Password</label>
                        <label>Current Password</label>                 
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="login-password" class="round full-width-input" />
                        <label>New Password</label>                 
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="login-password" class="round full-width-input" />
                        <label>Confirm New Password</label>                 
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="login-password" class="round full-width-input" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Change" class="button round blue image-right ic-right-arrow"></input>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </fieldset> 
        </form> 

        <div class="banner-box round">
            <label class="alt-label">Sponsored links </label>
            <table id="raw">
                <tr>
                    <td>                    
                        <a href="#" class="fr"><img src="./images/test.gif"/></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="fr"><img src="./images/test2.gif"/></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="fr"><img src="./images/test3.gif"/></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>                                        
        </div>      
    </div> <!-- end content -->
```

Comment: you are setting attribute and getting it in same servlet.I think this is causing problem.try to call another servlet when you are submting form and in that servlet use getAttribute().let me know if this works or not

Comment: I've just try the way you say, but the result is the same, null. I think the problem is that when you submit a form, the request object is restarted and loses the session. But I'm not sure. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does the button to continue invoke `getGoToMenu()`?  If not, can you post the servlet code where you're getting a null session?

Comment: Yes, that is my idea, if you don't want to change your password, click on "Go To Menu" and this button call the servlet. But when I check the session in the servlet, it's null. I tried with <jsp:forward> tag and with this, I get the session, but the problem is that this tag is executed before show the html page. If I could to "execute" the forward when I click the button, it will be fine.